# python: better ways to extract matched patterns?

Tags: python

I have some codes like the following. It searches each line in a file for some patterns and, if found, extract some string from the matched pattern. Each line will only match, if any, one pattern at most.  What's in the file are just text lines, some lines have something like hight=123, some medium=123, and some low=123.

```
with open(file) as r:
    for line in r:
        if re.search('high=\d+', line):
             p = re.search('high=(\d+)', line)
             high = p.group(1)
        elif re.search('medium=\d+', line):
             p = re.search('medium=(\d+)', line)
             medium = p.group(1)
        elif re.search('low=\d+', line):
             p = re.search('low=(\d+)', line)
             low = p.group(1)
        ...
```

Now I'm wondering if I can extract the matched part without doing a second search, as illustrated below with some invalid codes as an example. The patterns searched could be quite different from each other. The question here is if there's a way to extract the matched part after re.search() returns true.

```
with open(file) as r:
    for line in r:
        if re.search('high=(\d+)', line):
            high = _.group(1)    # invalid code, but looking for something like this.
        elif re.search('medium=(\d+)', line):
            medium = _.group(1)  # invalid code
        elif re.search('low=(\d+)', line):
            low = _.group(1)     # invalid code
        ...
```

Note I could have done the below, but that's not what I wanted.

```
with open(file) as r:
    for line in r:
        m = re.search('high=(\d+)', line)
        if m:
             high = m.group(1)
        else:
             m = re.search('medium=(\d+)', line)
             if m:
                 medium = m.group(1)
             else:
                 m = re.search('low=(\d+)', line)
                 if m:
                    low = m.group(1)
        ...
```

I had tried to compile the patterns first, such as the following, but I got the error "NameError: name '_' is not defined". I tried this with both python2 and python3. There're some peculiar behaves with _.group(1) (it worked in some cases). I may bring up the issue in a separate post.

```
h = re.compile('hight=(\d+)')
m = re.compile('medium=(\d+)')
l = re.compile('low=(\d+)')

with open(file) as r:
    for line in r:
        if h.search(line):
            high = _.group(1)
        elif m.search(line):
            medium = _.group(1)
        elif l.search(line):
            low = _.group(1)
        ...
```

Comment: It would help if you could give an example of the input and what you expect to generate from it.

Comment: @naktinis thanks. i added some explanation. actually the question is quite simple. after re.search() returns true, is there a way to get parts of the matched pattern, whatever it is? Perl lets you do that (the matched parts are saved in a global variable).

Comment: Python doesn't have automatic assignment to global variables. You could easily write a wrapper function to do it, but it's not built into the language.

Comment: @JohnY thanks. it's also good to know that Python simply lacks such feature. so I'll focus on something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_ holds the result of the last executed statement when you work in an interactive shell. It's just an ordinary variable in the context of a program.

So, if you don't want to do the search again, you have to store the match object, as you do in your 3rd code example.

If you want to avoid nesting the ifs, you can use continue :

```
with open(file) as r:
    for line in r:
        m = re.search('high=(\d+)', line)
        if m:
            high = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search('medium=(\d+)', line)
        if m:
            medium = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search('low=(\d+)', line)
        if m:
            low = m.group(1)
            continue
        ...
```

Edit, to answer your comment:

There is no general way to do what you want in Python:

- you don't have any automatic assignment of the results to a variable, like in Perl,
- you can't write

  if xxx = yyy:

to avoid writing = by mistake instead of ==

Though, there's always one way to do it:

```
import re


class Matcher:
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self._pattern = pattern
        self._compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        self._match = None

    def __str__(self):
        return '<Matcher> %s, matching %s' % (self._pattern, self._match)

    # match and search apply on the regex, and return the match object   
    def match(self, string):
        self._match = self._compiled_pattern.match(string)
        return self._match

    def search(self, string):
        self._match = self._compiled_pattern.search(string)
        return self._match

    # Other methods apply to the match object
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return  getattr(self._match, attr)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # instead of m = re.compile(...)
    m = Matcher(r'(high)=(\d+)')

    lines = ['high=4', 'nothing here']


    for line in lines:
        # you can use search and match just like on the re object
        if m.search(line):
            # then you can use all methods of Match objects
            print(m.groups())
            print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
            print(m.span())
```

So, it seems to behave just like you wanted!

Comment: Thanks. This surely works.  But I wanted to know if there's an alternative, something like shown in my second code example.  Apparently Python lacks such feature.

Comment: @Shiping - Python lacks the feature, but it's trivial to add it yourself. The class-based implementation shown here is more formal, some would say more proper. But you could simply use your own global variable and write an extremely short function to do the search and update the global.

Comment: Thanks. It works the way I wanted though I was hoping Python had something like that built in.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
import re
r = re.compile("(high|medium|low)=(\d+)")
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        match = r.search(line)
        if not match:
            continue
        lvl, val = match.groups()
        if lvl == "high":
            high = val
        elif lvl == "medium":
            medium = val
        elif lvl == "low":
            low = val
```

Comment: Thanks. What you posted should work for the cases I showed in my codes. But what I'm looking for is a more general way to extract the matched pattern after re.search() returns true without having to test anything else.

Comment: @Shiping `re.search` returns a `Match` object and not a boolean. The above code will work even if you replace `match` with `search`. If you want to test and then extract, you can either do `try..except` the same code above or assign the `Match` object returned by `re.search` and check if it's `None` or not.

Comment: @adifire - I don't think your edit is any closer to what OP is looking for. Actually it may be even worse. See their comment about Perl at the main question.

Comment: @JohnY Guess you are right, maybe I am missing something here. I thought the code should work as intended given the input.